# SQL Conditional Select Statement

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

How would I go about doing the following?

Given the tables, Recipe, RecipeItem, RecipeInstruction. How do I perform a SELECT only if the SELECT statement of Recipe returned results.

If Recipe exists, return RecipeItems and return RecipeInstructions.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. More detail?

Comment: If the Recipe doesn't exist, the SELECT will return no rows. Isn't this the same thing as "only if the SELECT statement of Recipe returned results"?

Comment: How about listing some of the fields to show how they can be related/joined? Is this any particular type of database?

Comment: -1 for not enough information, no starting code, no columns, no fields etc..

Comment: why did you choose the answer with two separate sql statements and both of them only return the child table entries and not the details from the recipe table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but assuming a key relationship, select statements of the form:

```
SELECT ri.* FROM Recipe r
JOIN RecipeItem ri ON ri.RecipeID = r.RecipeID
WHERE r.Name = @myName -- or other criteria

SELECT ris.* FROM Recipe r
JOIN RecipeInstructions ris ON ris.RecipeID = r.RecipeID
WHERE r.Name = @myName -- or other criteria
```

... will return recipe details only if that recipe ID exists.  This is the standard way to retrieve child items with SQL.

Comment: Thank sir, thats exactly what I was looking for. And yes, Recipe is the Parent Entity, RecipeItem and RecipeInstruction contain the foreign key of recipe.

Answer (score 0):

You want an INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT *
FROM Recipe
    INNER JOIN RecipeItem ON RecipeItem.RecipeID = Recipe.RecipeID
    INNER JOIN RecipeInstruction ON RecipeInstruction.RecipeID = Recipe.RecipeID
WHERE Recipe.[Name] = 'the recipe name'
```

This is assuming that both `RecipeItem` and `RecipeInstruction` have a foriegn key called `RecipeID` that links it back to the main `Recipe` table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, but your question is not clear:

```
Select RI.*
   , RInst.*
From Recipe AS R
inner join RecipeItem AS RI
on R.PK = RI.FK
inner join RecipeInstruction AS RInst
on R.PK = RInst.FK
```

The primary key (PK) needs to match the Foreign Key (FK) fields between these tables in some way. I'm going to suggest listing some fields.